# Highly frequent errors when playing Hypixel

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently, I have been playing Minecraft on Hypixel a lot. (I was doing skyblock, but that's not the point.)
However, a lot of times, when moving between servers, I get 1 of 2 possible errors:

1. An established connecting was forcibly terminated by the remote host.
2. An established connection was forcibly terminated by the software in your host machine.

I have optifine for performance, disabling it didn't help. I run 1.12 minecraft.

Comment: Error no. 2 sounds like you might have a firewall that's terminating your connection, although admittedly I've never seen this error before

Comment: nope, first thing I did when I reset was turn off the firewall since java got blocked a lot

Comment: Yeah the reason I say this is because host machine is referring to your computer. I would imagine there's a program somewhere messing with your incoming and outgoing connections. Perhaps even something on your router?

Comment: It could be router issues. I can't mess with the router, so no checkie.